# Unable to use syslogs to process logs in Fluentd and visualize them in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, fluentd, chronograf

I am following [this](https://docs.fluentd.org/how-to-guides/syslog-influxdb) and [this](https://w2.influxdata.com/blog/get-your-syslog-on/) guide to collect logs from syslog and process it in Fluentd and store/visualize in InfluxDB. I have some questions regarding this:

1. I have td-agent running, influxd, chronograf running. I have set up the syslog.conf file with host, password, port everything.
   I understand that localhost8888 is for chronograf and localhost 8086 is for influxdb (I have specified influxdb port to be 8086).
2. I have configured chronograf, rsyslog, influxdb and td-agent.
3. I am able to create a database as well. I am using this command to create a database:

```
curl -i -X POST 'http://0.0.0.0:8888/write?db=test' --data-binary 'task,host=server01,region=europe-west1 value=1 1434055562000000000'
```

4. I am able to add connection on chronograf, and view the "Explore" page.

But I am unable to view the syslog data on chronograf. I can't see data flowing into chronograf and unable to visualize it.

I tried using telegraf too, but it keeps saying `database "telegraf" creation failed: 401 Unauthorized` and `[telegraf] Error running agent: starting input inputs.syslog: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:6514: bind: address already in use`

I have macos M1 chip and I am using InfluxDB 2.4. Any help would be much appreciated. I am struggling since two days to figure this out.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using InfluxDB 1.8 or 2.4?

Comment: @mhall119 I am using Influxbd 2.4